# How to split the string based on particulat charactor in Dart | Flutter

Tags: flutter, date, dart, time, flutter-web

I'am getting a timestamp `2022-01-01T09:38:28.807+00:00`  from the api. I want to split it into date and time. Here from this timestamp i want to split it into 2 from T. for eg from this iam expecting the output. `String date = 2022-01-01`  and  `String time =09:38:28.807+00:00`. Based on that `T` charactor i want to split it into two. How to acheive this.

Comment: can you specify more or send code or whatever?

Comment: Did you look at the split method on String? https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/String/split.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 String _date_and_time = "2022-01-01T09:38:28.807+00:00";

 String date = _date_and_time.split("T")[0];
 String time = _date_and_time.split("T")[1];

 print("Date is : ${date}");
 print("Time is : ${time}");
```

Output

Date is : 2022-01-01

Time is : 09:38:28.807+00:00